# How recreate or refresh fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i have fragment for display the NavigationDrawer. In that i have the first section the header with some information. This information change and with EventBus i control this event, but how can update this fragment?

The implementation below work only if i rotate the device.

extract from MainActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity);


        mNavigationNavDrawerFragment = (Nav_DrawerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);
        mNavigationNavDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);


        inizialized(mServices);

    }

....
....

  EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new PersonDetails(mNomeCognome, mEmail));

 //HERE HOW CAN REFRESH OR RECREATE THIS mNavigationNavDrawerFragment?

}
```

Extract from Nav_DrawerFragment:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mDrawerList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mDrawerList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        final List<NavigationItem> navigationItems = getMenu();

       //HERE I SET THE UPDATE DATA
        Nav_adapter adapter = new Nav_adapter(navigationItems,mNomeCognome,mEmail);
        adapter.setNavigationDrawerCallbacks(this);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition,items);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        EventBus.getDefault().registerSticky(this);



    }

    public void onEventMainThread(PersonDetails event){

        mNomeCognome = event.mNomeCognome;
        mEmail = event.mEmail;

    }

public void setup(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {

        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) return;
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) return;
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();

            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you're using a `RecyclerView` with the adapter

```
Nav_adapter adapter = new Nav_adapter(navigationItems,mNomeCognome,mEmail);
```

and then you're updating the values that were used to create the adapter on the event

```
mNomeCognome = event.mNomeCognome;
mEmail = event.mEmail;
```

the problem is that you didn't pass those values to the adapter.

So you'll have to create a way to pass those updated values to the existing adapter, something like this:

```
// first define your adapter as a field:
Nav_adapter adapter;

// then on your event
public void onEventMainThread(PersonDetails event){
   mNomeCognome = event.mNomeCognome;
   mEmail = event.mEmail;
   adapter.setNewValues(mNomeCognome, mEmail);
}
```

then inside this `setNewValues` you update the adapter values and don't forget to call one of the [`notifyItemChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int)) or [`notifyItemRangeChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRangeChanged(int,%20int)) method on the adapter so that the new value can be updated on the screen.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer..i must call notifyItemChanged into setNewValues right?.. and also notifyDataSetChanged it work ?

Comment: yes, you should call the "notify___" methods as soon as the data changed. You should only call one or the other. The `notifyDataSetChanged` works, but it's not optimised, it invalidates all the views in the list and re-create/re-bind all of them. The methods where you specify exactly what changed, like `notifyItemChanged` only invalidate and re-bind that one specific position of your adapter.

Comment: this method notifyItemChanged need (int position) but how can get  it?

Comment: you gonna pass the position of the data that changed. For example, say `mNomeCognome` and `mEmail` are in the 3rd item of your adapter, then you should pass `3`. If for example `mNomeCognome` is the 4th item and `mEmail` is the 5th item, then you call `notifyItemRangeChanged(4, 2); // 4th position, 2 items`

Comment: sorry..in my example i have Nav_adapter(navigationItems,mNomeCognome,mEmail) so i try with:  notifyItemChanged(2) and  notifyItemChanged(3) but the data not change..

Comment: those values I commented were just examples. I really don't know how you're doing inside your `Nav_adapter`, you have to check on your code. Those values is the value of `position` for the method `@Override public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)` inside your adapter.